# Using an old version of node in VS Code debugger

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, keystonejs

I updated VS Code to 1.14.2 and am attempting to run an application that requires Node 6.x.  Prior to this update, the configuration I was using worked just fine:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/keystone.js"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Port",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

now, when I execute the program, it just hangs without starting (expected when I run with Node 7.x or above).  In addition, it provides the following message, which I'm not sure is relevant:

**Debugging with inspector protocol because Node.js v8.2.1 was detected.**

**node --inspect=38743 --debug-brk keystone.js**

**Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:38743/d4a20480-3a0f-4aa7-8882-aec756edd6da
Debugger attached.**

I'm using nvm to manage my Node versions, and `nvm list` provides the following (as you can see, I already have 6.11.0 aliased to default):

```
$ nvm list
->      v6.11.0
         v8.0.0
         system
default -> 6.11.0 (-> v6.11.0)
node -> stable (-> v8.0.0) (default)
stable -> 8.0 (-> v8.0.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/boron (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.8.4 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.11.1 (-> N/A)
```

I'm assuming it's not executing due to trying to use the wrong version of Node, and any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of VS Code introduced this option (I am using version 1.17.2) but in `launch.json`, we can explicitly specify which debug protocol to use.

So, to force VS Code to use `legacy` protocol, add `"protocol": "legacy"`

Here's your `launch.json` updated to include that key:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/keystone.js"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Port",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858,
            "protocol": "legacy"
        }
    ]
}
```